# Bank Statement for UK Visit Visa for Dependent

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

My Husband is on a dependent visa under me. We are planning t travel to London on Visit Visa for 1 week. Is it compulsory to show the bank statement of my husband or me being the main applicant can show my bank statement for both?

how much funds should I show for 1 week trip for 2?

Answer (score 6):

In the applications you contemplate, you are the primary and your husband is the dependent.

As far as evidence goes, the primary submits bank statements for the entire family and each dependent lists the primary's GWF number in their remarks section. The Entry Clearance Officer will know what to do.

So yes, you can show your bank statements for both.

Regarding your husband's bank statements... If he answers any question on his application that should be supported by bank statements, like his employment or his expenditures that he pays from his own account, then yes, he needs to submit his statements. Otherwise your husband leaves himself open to an ECO's challenge  (that's a bad thing). The fact that you are the one evidencing financial capacity does not reduce your husband's responsibility to prove what he claims.

Don't leave anything vulnerable to challenge in either application.

So you fill out the application first and write down your GWF number then give it to your husband to put in his remarks section.  When it comes time to print out the applications and take them to the VFS, you can make a neat and tidy pen and ink amendment to your remarks section that gives your husband's GWF number. That method ties both the applications together in a way that the system can find them.

Note: Re your subject line, it is always understood that visa questions are urgent.  "*My visa question is not urgent, I am very relaxed about it;  there's no hurry*" said no one. Ever. :)

See also [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

I forgot to add...  From the *'tips and techniques'* department: separate bank accounts can trip the ECO's radar. Make sure you include your original marriage certificate and any joint holdings you have like mortgage, tenancy agreements, children, etc etc. It's not a requirement to do this, but a stitch in time saves nine...